# How do I transfer the ownership of a Microsoft Edge Extension?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension, microsoft-edge-chromium

I would like to transfer the ownership of my Microsoft Edge extension. The party whom I would transfer the ownership will manage the updates and features of the extension, and I would no longer want to be associated with the extension.

Is there any way of transferring ownership?

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74949013/how-do-i-transfer-the-ownership-of-a-microsoft-edge-extension/74959260#74959260) helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Publish to the Microsoft Edge Add-ons website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/#publish-to-the-microsoft-edge-add-ons-website), extension is associated with developer account.

If you want to "transfer" the extension, you can only delete it from your developer account and re-publish the extension with that party's account.

Comment: This answer is crazy in 2024. Chrome, Opera, Firefox all allow extension transfers. I have an extension with 30,000+ Edge users, and I can't transfer it to the new developer after a sale of another site/extension on the same dev account.